# Squeaking Serpentine Belt

Tags: serpentine-belt, squeaking

I had a slightly squeaking serpentine belt, so I sprayed just a fast squirt of liquid wrench on the grooved side and it got real loud. I let it run for a few minutes and it still is loud. How do I clean this off and start over?

Comment: Could you check your CAPS key please?

Comment: Candle wax makes a good temporary belt lube.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. Go down to your local parts store and purchase a new serpentine belt and a can of carb cleaner (or brake clean).
2. Take the old belt off and throw it in the garbage. It's useless now that it has a lubricant sprayed on it.
3. Take the carb cleaner and some paper towels and *thoroughly clean* all of the pulleys where the belt made contact.
4. Install the new belt.
5. Call it a day.